# How can I translate the whole website in a single button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I'm new to reactjs, so basically I'm making a inform website , so my question is how can I translate all the texts in the website in a click of a button
Thank you.

Comment: Read about `react-i18next`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your application, and if it'll grow or not, you can use a library or do something yourself.

So basically, there's no mystery for how to have the languages: you need to store those texts in objects. You can have one object, for example:

```json
const content = {
  helloWorld: {
    enUS: 'Hello World',
    ptBR: 'Olá mundo',
  }
}
```

Or you can have two (or more) objects: `const contentEnUS = { helloWorld: 'Hello World' }` and `const contentPtBR = { helloWorld: 'Olá mundo' }`.

Of course, there are good and bad ways to manage this content, you can create a simple `.json` file, or you can use libraries such as [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/).

To display the content, instead of writing the content directly into the JSX, you'll always use the object key for that content. How to do that depends on how you will implement it, if you decide to use `react-i18next`, it has some solutions for that, if you do it yourself, you will need to use the Context API.

The Context API can store data to be used by components below the context provider. So, you'd basically store in the context the current language of your application, for example: `language = 'enUS`. Then you can access the context from your components and verify which language is, and use the object/property accordingly.

The button itself would change the language in the context. So just like a simple state, you'd have the `language` and the `setLanguage`, and provide those from your context. Then, all your content would consume `language` to display the content, and the button would use `setLanguage` to change the language (and by doing it so, reloading the entire content).

As the language is something shared throughout the website, you'll have to put your context on your root component, and by having a SPA (Single Page Application), the user could navigate throughout the application without having the language reset.

Of course that, by the language being heavily used by your application, it's better to use an external library with a more refined management than to do it on your own. But if you start it by doing it yourself and then moving to react-i18next, you will understand better how everything is working behind the scenes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There’s a great blog post with a step by step guide: https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/